# Backbone.Radio for inter-component communication

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, messaging

Say I have two components on a page, where the user may interact with one and the other one should update, say something like below:

```
 component A       |   component B
                   |
 - option 1 link   |   "stuff related to option 1"
 - option 2 link   |
```

Now when we click `option 2 link` we want component B to update.

MarionetteJS uses (or will so in the next major release) [Backbone.Radio](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.radio).

I would like to know the best way of doing this. 2 things come to mind:

1: Use same channel in both components

```js
// Component A
// ...
onOptionClick: function (evt) {
  Backbone.Radio.channel('AvsB').request('update:b', {id: this.model.get('id')});
}

// Component B
// ...
initialize: function () {
  Backbone.Radio.channel('AvsB').reply('update:b', function () {
    // update contents...
  }
}
```

2: Decouple even more, by using a mediator, eg: components should only use their "own" channel.

```js
// Component A
// ...
onOptionClick: function (evt) {
  Backbone.Radio.channel('compA').request('option:isUpdated', {id: this.model.get('id')});
}

// Mediator (eg. main.js, a controller, or whatever high-level object)
var channelCompA = Backbone.Radio.channel('compA');
var channelCompB = Backbone.Radio.channel('compB');
channelCompA.reply('option:isUpdated', channelCompB.request('content:shouldUpdate'));

// Component B
// ...
initialize: function () {
  Backbone.Radio.channel('compB').reply('content:shouldUpdate', function () {
    // update contents...
  }
}
```

Option 2 is more work and seems a bit unnecessary. But I can't really shake the feeling that option 1 is still too specific. After all, component A shouldn't care that component B exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that option 2 is needlessly complicated.

Basically, you're asking whether the Event Aggregator pattern or the Mediator pattern is more appropriate here. The main thing to keep in mind is that they are *both* solutions to tight coupling. That's obscured in your example because you're naming the requests after the component (`"update:b`"). That's the source of the coupling, not the fact that you're using the same channel.

More specifically, if component A and component B really don't need to know about each other then their names shouldn't be part of the API that is the request name. The request should be named after the actual work that should be done (`performUpdate`, perhaps?), not after who is doing the work.

Of course, it still might make sense to use different channels for organizational or namespacing purposes. And the Mediator pattern definitely has its uses (for example, if you need it to intercept the requests and alter them in some way). But there's no point in using it just to blindly route requests in an attempt to avoid coupling.

You might find [this article](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2013/03/18/event-aggregator-andorvs-mediator-a-tale-of-two-patterns/) by the creator of Marionette interesting, as it discusses the same issue.

Comment: Yeah you're right, choosing proper names (always difficult) and going for options 1 is the best way to go. Thanks for helping to get my thoughts in one direction ;)
I refactored my code and it looks so much cleaner now. Lovely.